# What is the correct way of using “appear”?

Tags: verbs

Let’s assume that i am bank officer. Can say the sentences below to my customer who asks how much dept he has to bank:

> Your dept appear to be $500.
>
> Your debt appear $500.
>
> İt appears that your dept is $500.

If those are wrong please show me correct way.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the only version where you've spelt ***debt*** correctly is the completely invalid #2. Version #1 is otherwise valid, apart from the fact that singular ***debt*** requires the singular verb form ***appears***.  And version #3 is just a slightly more roundabout way of putting it.

Answer (score 0):

Debt is singular, so the correct form of the verb *to appear* is *appears*. Also, debt is spelled D-E-B-T, no *P*. "Dept" is usually an abbreviation for "department".

With the correction to verb conjugation and the spelling of "debt", your first example is fine.

The second one is wrong (apart from spelling "debt" correctly). "Appears" can be used as a linking verb, that is where its object is an adjective, and in that case can be followed by *to be* or not - "you appear tired" or "you appear to be tired". However, when "appears to be" is followed by a noun, the *to be* needs to be there. "Your debt appears large" would be fine, but not "your debt appears $500".

The final one is fine, apart from the spelling of "debt".

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things to point out initially:

1. The correct spelling is "debt". You have this right only once, so I'm guessing you have some confusion around this. Perhaps it will help you in remembering to consider that the word "debt" is related to the word "debit".
2. You need to use "appears", as opposed to "appear", as we are speaking in a singular sense (one debt).

With that said, phrasings 1 and 3 are fine, while phrasing 2 is incorrect.

> Your debt appears to be $500.
>
> İt appears that your debt is $500.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last sentence is gramatically correct.  However, it does not make actual sense, because a department can not "be" $500.  A department is a department.  Currency is currency.  So, a department cannot be currency, which you have stated that it is in your third sentence.

Comment: It's a typographical error. It's supposed to be debt, I think.